Multi-targeting library and Dockerfile
I have an application project App that depends on a library project Lib. The dependency is a project reference: the library is not built into a NuGet package. Both target .NET 5. They are built using a Dockerfile that uses the mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:5.0 image. Everything works.
Suppose I need to edit the library so that it targets both .NET 5 and .NET 8. I switched Lib to multi-targeting by using
<TargetFrameworks>net5.0;net8.0</TargetFrameworks>

However, during the Docker build I get an error saying
The current .NET SDK does not support targeting .NET 8.0.  Either target .NET 5.0 or lower, or use a version of the .NET SDK that supports .NET 8.0.

Why is Lib built as if it was a .NET 8 project? Shouldn't the compiler realize that the dependent App project is .NET 5, and so build Lib as a .NET 5 library? Can I manage this multi-targeting scenario without the need to build all the libraries into NuGet packages?
